# Consistency of behaviour for files overwritten by Shade plugin

Tags: maven, maven-shade-plugin

I am generating a big Jar with maven-shade-plugin and have resource files with the same names in both the main jar and the dependencies. One of the files gets overwritten by another, which is fine as I want the one in the dependency to be a default version and the one in the main jar a more specific user one. I do not want to merge these files with e.g. *org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer*, I just need to be 100% sure that if two or more files have the same name then the one in the main jar file will always be the one kept in the uber-jar. 
Is that the way the shade plugin behaves?

Comment: Thought about using filters https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/includes-excludes.html

Comment: @khmarbaise That would not work. I don't want to filter the files coming from the dependencies. If there is no user specified file in the main jar, I still want the default one to be there.

Comment: Than you need to write your own transformer...

Comment: thanks, so you confirm that I can't expect maven-shade to consistently keep the file I need? Is that logic documented anywhere?

Comment: I couldn't find any documentation of that. It _may_ work with the current version but there's no guarantee that it won't change in the future.